# What is the reason to use these anonymous block to call super class method in this code?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

yesterday i saw an example of Combo box on oracle site on the link below:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/combo-box.htm#BABJCCIB

On this page there is an example under the section named **"Applying Cell Factories to Combo Boxes"**. In this example there is a code i am pasting here:-

```
priorityComboBox.setCellFactory(
            new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
                @Override public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
                    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>() {
                        {
                            super.setPrefWidth(100);
                        }    
                        @Override public void updateItem(String item, 
                            boolean empty) {
                                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                                if (item != null) {
                                    setText(item);    
                                    if (item.contains("High")) {
                                        setTextFill(Color.RED);
                                    }
                                    else if (item.contains("Low")){
                                        setTextFill(Color.GREEN);
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    setText(null);
                                }
                            }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
```

In the above code below code is used to call the super class method setPrefWidth.

```
{
  super.setPrefWidth(100);
}
```

Now my question is why they used the anonymous code block to do this. They can put that statement in the updateItem method.
What is the intention to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you could insert it into your updateItem-Method but then it would get called every time the item is updated.

This might not be a big Problem with setPrefWidth as nothing changes but imagine you have something like `firstInitialize();`which is not supposed to be called more than once.

Therefore you can use the Initializer Block. Otherwise you would have to add a variable like `bool isInitialized` where you check first, if the variable is true and in case it's not, you performe your Action.

You can also have a look at: [Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)